# Cannot update Progress table through ODBCDataAdapter/CommandBuilder

Tags: c#, odbc

I'm making a simple CRUD app in C# for any single table in our database, interfacing with a Progress database through an ODBC connection. I'm using an OdbcDataAdapter with an OdbcCommandBuilder attached to it.

OdbcCommandBuilder never seems to SET all the values in the row I change, providing incorrect SQL statements to the DataAdapter.

For example, in the Brown table, I change the Name column, but get the Update SQL where nothing is set:

```
"UPDATE \"PUB\".\"brown\" WHERE ((\"cust-num\" = ?) AND (\"cust-seq\" = ?))"
```

In the agent-d table, I change the Parent-Name column, but get the Update SQL to change the agent number:

```
"UPDATE \"PUB\".\"agent-d\" SET \"agent\" = ? WHERE ((\"agent\" = ?) AND (\"parent-num\" = ?) AND (\"cust-num\" = ?))"
```

Why am I not getting appropriate SQL from the OdbcCommandBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the Progress/OpenEdge DB and the ODBC Command Builder do not work together very well, which is why I was getting dumb Update statements.